# Get IP of network adapters and display in messagebox...gets errors when connection is not active

Tags: powershell, ip, messagebox

I am trying to have a pop up box come up when a user clicks on a desktop icon...this will provide them with their username, computer name, connected network IPs and other additional information...the code works properly, however if a network connection is not active, there is an error displayed in a powershell window. I was wondering if anyone could help with this? Basically if there is no connection, don't display anything...if there is a connection display the IP. Also would be nice to not have the powershell window open when running this...I think this can be accomplished with VBS? Thank you in advance.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$ethAddress = (Get-NetIPConfiguration -InterfaceAlias 'Ethernet' | Where-Object {$_.IPv4DefaultGateway -ne $null -and $_.NetAdapter.status -ne "Disconnected"}).IPv4Address.ipAddress
$wiAddress = (Get-NetIPConfiguration -InterfaceAlias 'Wi-Fi' | Where-Object {$_.IPv4DefaultGateway - ne $null -and $_.NetAdapter.status -ne "Disconnected"}).IPv4Address.ipAddress
$vpnAddress = (Get-NetIPConfiguration -InterfaceAlias 'VPN' | Where-Object {$_.IPv4DefaultGateway -ne $null -and $_.NetAdapter.status -ne "Disconnected"}).IPv4Address.ipAddress
$celAddress = (Get-NetIPConfiguration -InterfaceAlias 'Cellular' | Where-Object {$_.IPv4DefaultGateway -ne $null -and $_.NetAdapter.status -ne "Disconnected"}).IPv4Address.ipAddress
$pcname = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName()
$userName = $env:UserName
$serialNum = (gwmi win32_bios).SerialNumber
$model = (gwmi win32_computersystem).model
$manufacturer = (gwmi win32_computersystem).manufacturer
$buildNumber = (gwmi win32_operatingsystem).buildnumber
$releaseID = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" -Name ReleaseID).ReleaseID

[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please provide the following information for the IT  Technician.
`nUsername:`t$userName 
Computer Name:`t$pcname  
`nWired IP:`t`t$ethAddress
Wireless IP:`t$wiAddress
VPN IP:`t`t$vpnAddress 
Cellular IP:`t$celAddress
`nManufacturer:`t$manufacturer
 Model:`t`t$model
 Service Tag:`t$serialNum
 `nW10 Release ID:`t$releaseID
 W10 Build:`t$buildNumber",'PC Information','OK','Information')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7) (`>`) the error stream (`2`) to null and then check the variable for contents. Then you can choose to take action based on the variable contents. This will work because by default variables store success stream (`1`) results.

```
$ethAddress = (Get-NetIPConfiguration -InterfaceAlias 'Ethernet' |
    Where-Object {$_.IPv4DefaultGateway -ne $null -and $_.NetAdapter.status -ne "Disconnected"}).IPv4Address.ipAddress 2>null
$wiAddress = (Get-NetIPConfiguration -InterfaceAlias 'Wi-Fi' |
    Where-Object {$_.IPv4DefaultGateway - ne $null -and $_.NetAdapter.status -ne "Disconnected"}).IPv4Address.ipAddress 2>null
$vpnAddress = (Get-NetIPConfiguration -InterfaceAlias 'VPN' |
    Where-Object {$_.IPv4DefaultGateway -ne $null -and $_.NetAdapter.status -ne "Disconnected"}).IPv4Address.ipAddress 2>null
$celAddress = (Get-NetIPConfiguration -InterfaceAlias 'Cellular' |
    Where-Object {$_.IPv4DefaultGateway -ne $null -and $_.NetAdapter.status -ne "Disconnected"}).IPv4Address.ipAddress 2>null
if (!($ethAddress -and $wiAddress -and $celAddress -and $vpnAddress)) { exit }
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out tomorrow at work. I appreciate your help and explanation!!

Comment: Hey sorry, I forgot to comment back! This seemed to make it work...I just had to change the if from -and to -or

Thank you again!!